How combine presigned VersionedTransacctions in solana with js sdk
I want to combine presignes transaction into one.
 export const combineVersionedTransactions = (
      rawTransactions: VersionedTransaction[],
      blockhash: string,
      feePayer: PublicKey,
    ) => {
      const allInstructions: TransactionInstruction[] = [];
      rawTransactions.forEach((rawTransaction) => {
        allInstructions.push(...TransactionMessage.decompile(rawTransaction.message).instructions);
      });
    
      const combinedMessage = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: feePayer,
        recentBlockhash: blockhash,
        instructions: allInstructions,
      }).compileToV0Message();
    
      return new VersionedTransaction(combinedMessage);
    };

This function combines multiple VersionedTransactions, but if any transaction has been already signed, it invalidates and looses that signed signature and Signature Verification fails.
So my question is how preserve already signed transactions so combining wont reset transaction and wont require to sign again?

You can’t keep existing signatures when combining VersionedTransactions. Changing the transaction (like combining instructions) alters the message, which makes the signatures invalid.
To handle this:

Combine Before Signing: Add all instructions into one new transaction and sign it after combining.
Use Durable Nonces: Keeps transactions valid longer, but you’ll still need to re-sign the combined transaction.
Send Separately: Just submit the transactions one at a time without combining them.


Yeah, make sense. I thought it is possible to reassign transaction signatures, like this
const signatures = combinedTransaction.signatures getting and  adding like this combinedTransaction.addSignature(signatures).
But that still  shows invalid or missing signatures for  public keys.
